# Missing chunks when creating file with AudioQueue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, avaudiorecorder, audioqueueservices

So a .wav file has a few standard chunks. In most of the files I work with, the "RIFF" chunk is first, then a "fmt " chunk, then the "DATA" chunk. When recording using AVAudioRecorder, those chunks are created (although an extra "FLLR" is created before the "DATA" chunk.)

When creating a file with AudioQueue, those standard chunks aren't created. Instead, AudioQueue creates, in order, "caff","desc","lpcm","free", and "data" chunks.

What's going on? Aren't the "RIFF" and "fmt " chunks required? How does one force the inclusion of those chunks?

I'm creating a file by:

AudioFileCreateWithURL(URL, kAudioFileCAFType, &inputDataFormat, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &AudioFile);

with inputDataFormat being a AudioStreamBasicDescription with a full complement of properties.

So how does one write, at least, the "RIFF" and "fmt " chunks with AudioQueue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So a .wav file has a few standard chunks. …
>
> When creating a file with AudioQueue, those standard chunks aren't created. …
>
> ⋮
>
> I'm creating a file by:
>
> ```
> AudioFileCreateWithURL(URL, kAudioFileCAFType, &inputDataFormat, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &AudioFile);
> ```

Let this be an example of the value of showing one's code in one's question. :-)

`kAudioFileCAFType` is a Core Audio File, not a WAV file. Try `kAudioFileWAVEType` instead.

Comment: I could kiss you! Thank you!!